# Is there a way to auto scroll down and load more content of any website that uses infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question is out of curiosity. These days one can find numerous websites that use "Load more on scroll down" feature . For: Facebook, twitter, instagram etc.
Is there a way to automate this on any website? 
I bumped into [this](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=758) 
but I have no clue how to make this work.

I know some javascript and jquery.

Comment: You should probably use a browser extension for that, there is Autopager (firefox only but highly customisable and easy rule creation) or Autopagerize (firefox/chrome).

Comment: Try this one   http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll  OR  http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Comment: @AbrarKhan I dont think you undertood the question. I am not looking for a way to add this feature in my website .I am looking for a way to automatically trigger load more on any website perhaps using iframe or something.,

Comment: the way which you are thinking is Impossible, i think some plugins can do that

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know there's no automated way to make this work on every website available out there. E.g if you're developing a Wordpress blog and want to load more posts when the user reaches the bottom of the page you have to make an ajax-call to a php function to load more. And you have to define that function.

If you're on a Drupal site you have to follow the same step, however the Wordpress API and Drupal API are not the same so you have to customize the php function to load more.

The only "automated" way I can think of is to load all posts(Wordpres) or nodes(Drupal) and hide a certain number of them whith css. And when the user reaches the bottom, unhide XXX number of posts and repeat this step until every post is revealed.